# MongoDB Compass filter (query)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

[image]

In mongoDB compass I am getting no result with the below filters. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

1. `{user: {uid: 'ttorone'}}`
2. `{user: {_id: ObjectId("5b9fc9567a1f050026a8bbda")}}`

What I want is to filter out this document (where user-> uid is 'ttorone'). User is also an object here.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try like this {"user.uid" : "ttorone"}

For example if I would like to get all movies documents that have "imbd.id" equals to 1, I put the following filter in the compass, see the image below. Your situation is similar. You are searching for property value in the embedded object.

[image]